# What is the adjectival form of "place"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, morphology, derivation

*Space* is to *spatial* as *place* is to what adjective?

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence in which you'd use it?

Comment: The analogous word is 'palacial'

Comment: @Mitch is that a joke, or were you thinking *spacious*?

Comment: *oriented*? Or *well-oriented*, following from *spatially aware*?

Comment: @stevesliva you know, big like a palace, with lots of places inside.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using *place*’s closest synonym *location*, from which you can use the adjective *locational*.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context and what you actually mean by "place," consider [local](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/local).

**local**: pertaining to or characterized by place or position in space; spatial (Dictionary.com)

Answer (score 0):

In academic contexts you may consider also using **topological**. Its etymology comes from the Greek word *topos* which means a *place*.

Comment: Note that in a scientific context, *topological* means *relating to the way something is connected* and not *related to place.*  Thus I consider it very unlikely that it answers the question. However, given the lack of context, …

Answer (score 0):

*Positional* -- Of or relating to or determined by position ([WordWeb](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/POSITIONAL)).